# Some php files are downloaded while some are properly executed

Tags: php, apache2, php-7.0

I have Ubuntu 16, Apache 2.4.41 running multiple domains and recently upgraded from php 5.6 to 7.0.33.
I have both WordPress and Presta in two different domains.

Most of php files are running fine, but some are just downloaded by browser.

I tried to rename them, but the problem remains so it's not linked to filename.
I already switched some entries in DirectoryIndex, no change.
I tried to put more trace on Apache2 and php, but no error is given.

An example of code file which is downloaded (while others are properly executed):
(I removed the comments)

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: Which one is downloaded? The file containing that code, or `'/wp-blog-header.php'`? PHP looks at the file extension: `.php`. You should at least address that in your question.

Comment: The code sample is irrelevant to your server and PHP SAPI configuration woes. Checklist: [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](//stackoverflow.com/q/5121495)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Prestashop and WP were working fine before upgrade. After upgrade they only partially work. Some links download files, some work. The example is what is downloaded.

Comment: @mario I don't understand your comment. I already went through the page your reference. Php 7.0.33 is active. As said most of the website, made of php, works and is reachable from internet. Short tag is on. Only few links download file.

Comment: Permissions and owners are the same on working and non-working files.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the reason why some pages load and some not. The sites were originally built in http and migrated to https. Both are still supported, but the php configuration was not consistent for http and https. So because some links still point to http and were failing while https was ok, it looked not consistent to user.
I aligned all config files and it fixed the issue.